# Story about two sisters and a winged lion

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I read a book about 7-8 years ago about two sisters. I think it was (kind of) a young adult's book, but I really want to finish the series, so I'm asking for help finding the book I read. Okay, these are the details I remember:

- Both sisters are princesses, one is supposed to protect the other
- One of the princesses has a winged lion (I can't remember the name of the lion)
- When the princess supposed to protect the other princess is scared, the lion says something about "flying high and seeing the stars"? Or something like that.
- They meet again after some time because of some important thing
- Apparently, the two have to convince a superbeing or something to keep the continent safe.

With this information, can someone help me find what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Possibly [Journey Across the Hidden Islands](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25488323-journey-across-the-hidden-islands) by Sarah Beth Durst.

[image]

> The traditional Emperor’s Journey is meant to be uneventful. But as the princesses Seika and Ji-Lin—twin sisters—travel to pay respects to their kingdom’s dragon guardian, unexpected monsters appear and tremors shake the earth. The Hidden Islands face unprecedented threats, and the old rituals are failing. With only their strength, ingenuity, and flying lion to rely on, can the sisters find a new way to keep their people safe?

I cannot find a copy to check, but the description broadly matches and it was published in 2017 so the timing is about right. And if the cover is to be believed it does feature a flying lion!